# Trying to print average grade using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql, loops

Im trying to print out the average grade from letter grades from one of my coloumns in my table. It work for the first two inputs but after that when I keep adding the average is no longer true, I'm not sure what is going on.

*I relize this isnt the cleanest code

```
$totalGrade =0;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,grade FROM gpa");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    if($row['grade'] == 'A') {
        $numberGrade = 4;
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'A-') {
    $numberGrade = 3.67;
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'B+') {
    $numberGrade = 3.33;    
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'B') {
    $numberGrade = 3;    
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'B-') {
    $numberGrade = 2.67;
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'C+') {
    $numberGrade = 2.33;    
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);                                                                                
} if ($row['grade'] == 'C')  {
    $numberGrade = 2;
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);
} if ($row['grade'] == 'C-') {
    $numberGrade = 1.67; 
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);                                                                                
} if ($row['grade'] == 'D')  {
    $numberGrade = 1;  
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);                                                                         
} else {
    $numberGrade = 0;  
    $totalGrade = ($totalGrade + $numberGrade);                                                                         
}
$totalGrade = $totalGrade/$row['id'];
}
```

Comment: You might want to check out the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement... it would be a lot easier to look at/manage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two problems:

`$totalGrade = $totalGrade/$row['id'];` should NOT be inside the loop, which it currently is. Move it outside your while loop.

`$totalGrade = $totalGrade/$row['id'];` is dividing by the ID of the row.  You can't rely on that being represented of the number of grades that were added up.

Instead, put *before* your loop:

```
$count = 0;
```

Then, inside your loop, put:

```
$count++;
```

Then, finally, **outside** your loop, put:

```
$totalGrade = $totalGrade/$count;
```

**Finally**, there's a much more elegant (and easier to maintain) method of doing this, utilizing an array map or similar.  I'd strongly suggest looking into it.

Basically, before the loop, set up an array like so:

```
$grade_values = array(  'A' => 4.0,
                        'A-'=> 3.67,
                        'B' => 3.0,
                        ...etc...
);
```

Then, your entire function can look like so:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $totalGrade+= ($grade_value[$row['grade']]);
    $count++;
}
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
$totalGrade = $totalGrade/$count;
```

Maintenance is simpler.  It's a fraction of the code.  And it's more pleasant to look at!

Ok, and **finally finally**, you should not use mysql.  You should either use mysqli or PDO.  Mysql is deprecated, and insecure, and so on: [PHP documentation on mysql](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to @cale_b's answer by showing you an alternative to all those conditionals that I like. You can use an array instead, have a look

```php
<?php
$totalGrade = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id,grade FROM gpa");

$grades = array(
    'A'  => 4,
    'A-' => 3.67,
    'B+' => 3.33,
    'B'  => 3,
    'B-' => 2.67,
    'C+' => 2.33,
    'C'  => 2,
    'C-' => 1.67,
    'D'  => 1
);

$totalGrade = 0;
$numGrades  = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $numberGrade = 0;
    $grade       = $row['grade'];

    if(isset($grades[$grade]))
        $numberGrade = $grades[$grade];

    $totalGrade = $totalGrade + $numberGrade;
    $numGrades++;
}

$totalGrade /= $numGrades;
```